# No sé si me está haciendo bien la conexión desde PHP a MS Access

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access

Estoy ahora mismo trabajando en la conexión de PHP a una base de datos de MS Access. La he configurado en herramientas administrativas y a priori todo está OK, pero el testeo me hace dudar de ello. A ver, el código es el siguiente:

```
$conMSAccess=odbc_connect("msaccess-prueba", "", "");
$resultMSAccess=""; 

    if($conMSAccess){
        $resultMSAccess="Connected to MS Access DB";
    } else {
       $resultMSAccess= "Problems MS Access";
       odbc_errormsg();
    }

//Aquí veo qué registros de la tabla de MS Access no existen en la BD de MySQL
         $DBchangesMS = [];

    // Recorrer arreglo de resultados MSAccess
    foreach($datosPK_MS as $idPedido => $idarticulo) {
    // Si el pedido no existe en resultados de MySQL
        if(!isset($datosPK_MS[$idPedido])) {
            // Agregar al arreglo
            $DBchangesMS[] = ['IdPedido' => $idPedido, 'idarticulo' => $idarticulo];
        } 
    }

    var_dump($DBchangesMS);


 $querypruebaMS= "SELECT idarticulo FROM pedidos WHERE IdPedido='ZZZZYYYYP'";
    $lecturapruebaMS=odbc_exec($conMSAccess, $querypruebaMS);
    $RSpruebaMS=odbc_fetch_row($lecturapruebaMS);

    var_dump($lecturapruebaMS);
    var_dump($RSpruebaMS);
```

Lo que me está devolviendo el programa al ejecutarlo en XAMPP es lo siguiente:

```
array(0) { } 
resource(8) of type (odbc result) bool(true)
```

El array que me devuelve vacío es el que me tiene que sacar un registro que existe en la BBDD de MS Access que en la de MySQL a la que me tengo que conectar luego no existe. Por tanto, no debería devolver un array vacío. Pero, además, al hacer una consulta de prueba para ver si ese idarticulo está en la BBDD de MS Access, a partir de ese IdPedido, me devuelve un true pero no me devuelve el idarticulo en concreto. ¿En qué estoy fallando? ¿Hace la conexión bien o no la está haciendo? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Lo he resuelto con este código:

```
    $querypruebaMS= "SELECT idarticulo FROM pedidos WHERE IdPedido='ZZZZYYYYP'";
    $lecturapruebaMS=odbc_exec($conMSAccess, $querypruebaMS);
    $RSpruebaMS=odbc_fetch_row($lecturapruebaMS);
    $x=odbc_result($lecturapruebaMS, "idarticulo");

    var_dump($lecturapruebaMS);
    var_dump($RSpruebaMS);
    var_dump($x);
```

Por lo que he entendido, odbc_fetch_row te trae una fila de información, pero para acceder a los resultados de cada campo necesitas utilizar odbc_result.